# Delete specific rows in R which only differ by one column

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

---

I created a data frame which should have one observation per Country and Year. I have a binary variable (V1) which provides both (0 and 1) for one year and country. This results in the following table:

```
ID  
132     1 58 15 15 2014    Australia       Yes
133     0 58 15 15 2014    Australia       Yes
134     0 58 15 15 2015    Australia       Yes
135     0 58 15 15 2016    Australia       Yes
136     0 58 15 15 2017    Australia       Yes
137     1 58 15 15 2017    Australia       Yes
138     1 58 15 15 2018    Australia       Yes
139     0 58 15 15 2018    Australia       Yes
140     0 58 15 15 2019    Australia       Yes
141     0 57 15 15 2020    Australia       Yes
```

In the case of multiple observations in the same year and country, I want to keep only those observations, which hold values of 1 of the V1 variable.

Comment: `df[df$V1 == 1,]`? (if `df` is your data set)

Comment: Thanks for your fast reponse, but I want to keep observations of 0 if in the same year isn't an observation of a 1.

Comment: Then just run `df[!duplicated(df[, c("Country", "Year")]), ]` and you don't even need to create `V1` in the first place

Answer (score 2):

For each `country` and `year` you can select rows if number of rows in group is 1 or `V1 == 1`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(country, year) %>% filter(n() == 1 | V1 == 1)
```

The equivalent in `data.table` would be :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N == 1 | V1 == 1], .(country, year)]
```